# Perl, How to delete a hash in array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an Array of Hashes as below.

```
@students= (
    {
        'math' => 95,
        'phy'  => 90,
        'che'  => 85
    },
    {
        'math' => 50,
        'phy'  => 70,
        'che'  => 35
    }
);
```

I want to delete a entire hash based on some conditions, for that i tried with below code but am getting an error saying `delete argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or slice`. So please help me, how can i do?

```
for $i ( 0 .. $#students) {
    for $key ( keys %{ $students[$i] } ) {
        if ($key eq 'che') {
            if ($students->{$key} == 35){
                delete (%{$students[$i]});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$students[$i]->{$key}`?

Comment: Like @Barmar said, you be deleting the item, not the array

Comment: Actually, I was asking about the `if` line, not `delete`.

Comment: @Barmar yep yo r right..

Comment: Once that condition satisfies i want to delete that entire hash..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deleting is well suited for hash keys, but in your case you want to remove array elements so `grep` filtering could be applied:

```
@students = grep { $_->{che} != 35 } @students;
```